# Trying to embed a custom javascript google map into a wordpress site

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, wordpress

I am trying to embed a custom google map into a worpress site. Custom as in I cannot just copy and paste the html code that google would provide for one of their basic google maps, it is dynamic and written in javascript. The way I am trying to do it now is by typing the javascript code into a text widget in the sidebar and using `google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);` in the javascript to generate the map in a `<div>` on the page with id "map_canvas". Upon loading the page and inspecting it, the `<div>` loads, and the javascript runs without any error but no map shows up on the page. Intuitively it seems like the map is just too big to fit in the `<div>`, and when I check the style tag of the map_canvas `<div>` it does have `overflow: hidden` as part of the css. So changed it to visible which still didn't solve the problem. So now I am stuck... Does anyone have any experience with using javascript with wordpress and could help me out? I've tried to be as detailed as possible but if you need to know any more please let me know. Much appreciated!

Comment: What is the size of the map div?  Try setting it to a fixed size inline to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way for you to add the JavaScript to the header would be by using wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script(). You can add this into the functions.php file.

I'm not entirely sure whether JS executes in a text widget, so you would be better adding this into the page template that you need this to appear on.

It's impossible to tell whether you have styles overriding the div that contains the map, so it may be a good idea to post a link perhaps?

Comment: If you can put the script in the footer without causing too much screen flicker/movement, do it.